# How to fix connection since C# to connect to dbf remotely (shared file)

Tags: c#, visual-foxpro, dbf

I have a web service in C#, this is running in IIS and it's using DBF like DDBB, now I'm getting the information from local dbf on disk "C:\usr\content\", but now I need to change the DBF's path to a shared file on the same network that the web server.

When I run the web service on local I have access to read the remote DBF and work fine, but when I published the web service I got this error

> 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x1fd8 Thread 0x1a28 DBC 0x51f8d6c Xbase'

For the connection, I'm using OdbcConnection in some method and OleDb in others

This is the String Connection:

```
 const String route = @"\\192.168.1.99\f\usr\PANAMA";
    const String route2 = @"I:\usr\";


    public const String CCVEND = @"Driver={Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)};collatingsequence=ASCII;dbq="+ route + ";defaultdir="+ route + @";deleted=0;driverid=533;fil=dBase 5.0;filedsn="+ route2 + "connection.dsn;maxbuffersize=2048;maxscanrows=8;pagetimeout=5;safetransactions=0;statistics=0;threads=3;usercommitsync=Yes";
```

Where the default file it's on remote, I using this String connection on others method:

```
OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;Collate=Machine;" +
              @"NULL=NO;DELETED=YES;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;SourceDB=" + route)
```

In both case work fine when I run it on the Visual Studios (Local), the problem is when I published.

Need I to change something to get the remote connection?

**Annexed**: this is the method that I'm using and it's working fine in local

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("inventory/{ruta}")]
    public List<Inventory> GetInventory(String ruta)
    {

        List<Inventory> Ccclie = new List<Inventory>();


        DateTime date = DateTime.Today;

        int day = (int)date.Day;
        int month = date.Month;
        int year = date.Year;

        try
        {

            using (OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;Collate=Machine;" +
              @"NULL=NO;DELETED=YES;BACKGROUNDFETCH=NO;SourceDB=" + route))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM ccinven WHERE ruta = " + ruta+" and creacion = datetime("+year+", "+month+", "+day+")", con)) //20
                {
                    // OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    OdbcDataReader DbReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                        while (DbReader.Read())
                        {


                            Ccclie.Add(new Inventory
                            {
                                Cod1 = (DbReader["Cod1"].Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : DbReader["Cod1"].ToString().Trim(),
                                Codigo = (DbReader["Codigo"].Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : DbReader["Codigo"].ToString().Trim(),
                                Descrip = (DbReader["Descrip"].Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : DbReader["Descrip"].ToString().Trim(),
                                Precio = (DbReader["Precio"].Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : DbReader["Precio"].ToString().Trim(),
                                Num = (DbReader["Num"].Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : DbReader["Num"].ToString().Trim(),
                                Cantidad = (DbReader["Cantidad"].Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : DbReader["Cantidad"].ToString().Trim(),
                                Ruta = (DbReader["Ruta"].Equals(DBNull.Value)) ? "" : DbReader["Ruta"].ToString().Trim()

                            });
                        }



                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Ccclie.Add(new Inventory
            {
                Cod1 = ex.ToString()
            });

        }

        return Ccclie;


    }
    //++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Try adding a virtual directory to your app pointing to the network location. Just assign required permissions.

Comment: @MauricioAtanache thx for the answer, but I tried too and nothing

Comment: Are you getting the same error?

Comment: @MauricioAtanache yes the same error ---------------- System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException (0x80131937): ERROR [HY024] [Microsoft] [ODase dBase Driver] '(unknown)' is not a valid path. Make sure that the path is written correctly and that it is connected to the server where the file is located. \ R \ nERROR [01000] [Microsoft] [ODase dBase Driver] General warning Unable to open the key 'Temporary (volatile) Jet DSN for process 0x1f0 Thread 0x1888 DBC 0x5498fd4 Xbase 'of the Registry. \

Comment: And OleDb connection is also throwing an error?

Comment: @MauricioAtanache the error it's 'invalid path'

Comment: Have you tried opening a cmd with admin privileges and run Net use to map the network drive in the case of the constant route?